# Adding new Attributes to ACL in Symfony 2

Tags: symfony, acl

I'm new to Symfony, for my project I'm trying to use ACL and their Permission Attributes. In the cookbook it says that the permission map is by no means static and could be completely replaced at will. I need to create two other attributes, one Proposer and the other Acceptance. Something like where a user can propose new pages or comments and another one can decide if it can be published or not. Just for the moment I can't find how to implement this with ACL. Anyone has a clue or reference I could start from? I already read about ACL in the cookbook and the advanced use of it but it did not help me.

Comment: Well, i didn't have any answer concerning the ACL in Symfony a part the fact that i shoudln t use them. Everybody keeps telling me to use Voters. ACL to heavy in the database for a lot of entities. So i guess not gona be asking again about ACL.

Answer (score 0):

What you looking for is more related to a rules engine than ACL.

You can have a look on the following link for a quick implementation :

http://knpbundles.com/rezzza/RulerBundle